# Complex strcuture as CPT or taxonomy for use in woocommerce product variations

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce, I've got a bunch of products, which all have a certain material assigned.

My current implementation of a material is a CPT (with about 20 fields (color, transparancy, reflection, shininess, etc.) stored as post-meta (not one big aray, but individual entries)). Since multiple products can share the same material, a product simply holds the id (again as post-meta) of the material-post assigned to it.

Now I want to create product-variations solely based on different materials. In order to create a variable product, one has to specify an attribute on which the variations are based.

So my question is: Should a material better be implemented as a taxonomy?

Thoughts one the subject:

- Wordpress doesn't implement a way to add meta values to taxonomies, but woocommerce does  by using `update_woocommerce_term_meta`. But by going this way, my material terms will contain a huge amount of data, compared to what woocomemrce uses this feature for (just adding a thumbnail image id to product categories). Is this a bad design choice or are there any other downsides?
- I read about [custom fields for varations](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/), which would enable me to stick with my current implementation of material as a CPT, but then, how would I even create variations whithout material being an attribute?
- I could make both a CPT and a taxonomy, where the latter can be used for varations and its terms simply hold the id of the corresponding material-post, but that requires additional track-keeping, because each time a term is added or removed, the corresponding material-post should be added or deleted as well. Doesn't sound like a good solution...

What are your thoughts, opinions and suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the function update_woocommerce_term_meta(), you would recognize it just uses the wordpress function update_metadata(), which essentially means that woocommerce is using meta values, just like you do in you CPT.
With this in mind, I wouldn't think this procedure would slow down your site + your keeping compatibility by using existing functions.
Also 20 extra rows per taxonomy should not be considered "huge amount of data"

Comment: Thanks, @Jeppe that was kind of the answer I was looking for. Since I'm new to Wordpress, I just wanted to make sure that I'm not doing anything stupid out of ignorance. If you change your comment into an answer I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Glad to help, hope your project evolves well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the function update_woocommerce_term_meta(), you would recognize it just uses the wordpress function update_metadata(), which essentially means that woocommerce is using meta values, just like you do in you CPT. With this in mind, I wouldn't think this procedure would slow down your site + your keeping compatibility by using existing functions.

Also 20 extra rows per taxonomy should not be considered "huge amount of data"